# How do I keep a new line character in an IFTTT recipe

Tags: if-this-then-that

I am using IFTTT.com to watch my Flickr photostream and make a WordPress post. The IFTTT recipe uses:

```
{{FlickrUrl}}<br>
{{Description}}<br>
<a href="{{FlickrUrlShort}}">via Flickr</a>
```

The `<br>` after the `{{FlickrUrl}}` is not being parsed. I end up with 'br' on the end of the photo URL and the link doesn't work.

For example

```
http://www.flickr.com/photos/brantwinter/8853319926
```

is being added to the blog as:

```
http://www.flickr.com/photos/brantwinter/8853319926br
```

The br is breaking the URL string

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just add a regular old carriage return to the line? As far as I know IFTTT doesn't support HTML in fields.

Comment: You might also contact support@ifttt.com with the recipe ID. I've found them to be very responsive.

Answer (score 4):

So the awesome guys at IFTTT sorted this out for me:

```
[embed]{{FlickrUrl}}[/embed]<br>
{{Description}}
```

The [embed] tags were the answer !

Comment: so, do you still need the <br> tags, if the [embed] tags were the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Also, using only `br` tag works for me !

```
{{FlickrUrl}}<br>
```