# How do I insert a line break in an IFTTT recipe?

Tags: if-this-then-that

How can I insert a line break in an IFTTT recipe I am using to send Favorited Tweets to Facebook? Right now everything just runs together in one paragraph and looks very cluttered. Here's the recipe:

```
Dave favorited this tweet<br>
{{Text}} (@{{UserName}})<br>
{{LinkToTweet}}
```

I have tried using the `"<br>"` tag, but IFTTT just ignores it (or perhaps Facebook is ignoring it?).

Comment: You might try \n which is the js equivalent - this post also seems relevant http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44775/how-do-i-keep-a-new-line-character-in-an-ifttt-recipe

Comment: Yea, I saw that post, but it was ambivalent since the guy's solution didn't seem to jive with his code (a "br" tag outside of the "embed" tags). I'll try the "\n." Thanks

Comment: How do I use the java "\n"?  Would it be like "Dave favorited this tweet \n"?

Answer (score 4):

I entered

```
A human favorited a tweet<br>
{{Text}} (@{{UserName}})<br>
{{LinkToTweet}}
```

and got the following on FB. Seems to work.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**For Facebook Applets**

In Facebook, it requires two whitespace "padding" for linebreaks to display properly.

```
<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>
```

Adding the the code above between two paragraphs you intend to separate produces an empty line between two paragraphs. E.g.

```
This is paragraph one.

This is paragraph two.
```

This code inserts Paragraph 2 in the next line immediately, without an empty line in between:

```
<br>&nbsp;<br>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's my current code:
[image]

And, here's the result I'm seeing:
[image]

I don't think the "`<br>`" tags are working. I doubled up on them so there should be a blank line and there is not (Note: I also added quotes around the Text tag after this latest post).

Answer (score -2):

You need change encoding of txt file to UTF for 
 tags to work.